# Jupyter Notebook: Display local html files side by side

Tags: python, html, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, figure

how can I display (and scale) two local html files in the Jupyter Notebook side-by-side?
I failed to transfer a solution for images to html files...

```
 from IPython.display import IFrame
 from IPython.core.display import display, HTML

 # display single local image >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
 IFrame(src='figure1.html', width=1660, height=800)
```

This does not work:

```
  display(HTML("<table><tr><td><img src='fig1.html'></td><td><img src='fig2.html'></td></tr></table>"))
```

- Is it possible to load this figure into the first column of an html
  table and add another to the second column?

The ultimate idea is to export the notebook as slides and have two interactive plots on the slides.